# Aristotle quote on slaves believing they are slaves?

Tags: aristotle

Years ago I read a quote attributed to Aristotle:

> The remarkable thing about slavery is that slaves believe they are
> slaves.

What was the actual quote?

Comment: Hello TDK: I doubt very much if the quotation is from Aristotle, who found nothing remarkable about slavery. In Politics, I, he introduces a theory of 'natural slavery' intended to justify ethically the enslavement of certain people - the main characteristic of whom was that they were incapable of deliberation and foresight. (Apparently all 'barbarians were natural slaves!) Here also and in VII he offers remarks on the uses to which such people - 'living tools' - could properly be put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aristotle, *Politics*, 1254<sup>b</sup>20](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Aristot.%20Pol.%201.1254b&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0057):

> For he is by nature a slave who is capable of belonging to another (and that is why he does so belong), and who participates in reason so far as to apprehend it but not to possess it.
>
> ἔστι γὰρ φύσει δοῦλος ὁ δυνάμενος ἄλλου εἶναι (διὸ καὶ ἄλλου ἐστίν), καὶ ὁ κοινωνῶν λόγου τοσοῦτον ὅσον αἰσθάνεσθαι ἀλλὰ μὴ ἔχειν.

Comment: What are the exact citations from [Aristotle's works](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DAristotle%22)?

Comment: @Geremia. The first one is from Works of Aristotle: Politica, by B. Jowett. Oeconomica, by E. S. Forster. Atheniensium respublica, by Sir F. G. Kenyon. 1921 (ed. 1921).  Although numerous websites have the second quote, I was unable to find anything more specific than a general cite to Aristotle by name.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question, though. The first quote isn't about slaves believing they are or liking to be slaves.

Comment: @Geremia. Well, as I say, these are as close as I could get. Maybe Geoffrey Thomas (comment, above) was right in doubting that the source was Aristotle.